# Disable parent window while child window is opened using javascript

Tags: javascript

- I have a parent window named worklist.jsp
- Parent window has a button. on click of the button, it calls a function named getEventLogUser().
- getEventLogUser() function in turns calls a function named popupWindowWithPost() which opens the child window. both the function is in separate js file(utility.js)..
- My need is, i have to disable the parent window when child is opened.

worklist.jsp:

```
<div class="claro" id="menuDiv21" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'x','navMenu21');" onmousedown="setMenuBarProperty('navMenu21');" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="border:1px dotted white; left: auto; position: absolute; top: 620px;">
     <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBar" id="navMenu21" style="font-size:11pt;" title="MenuBar">
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="SearchMenu21" onclick="getEventLogUser();setMenuId(this.id);" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="SearchMenu21" name="search5.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/search.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Search
          </div>
</div>
</div>
```

utility.js:

```
function getEventLogUser(){
        var dummyvar = document.getElementById("CWPROCESSEVENTLOG.OBJECT_ID").value;
        popupWindowWithPost("eventLogUser.jsp",'height=600px,width=960px,top=50px,left=150px,scrollbars=no,sizable=yes,toolbar=no,statusbar=no','processManager',dummyvar);
}
function popupWindowWithPost(url, windowoption, name, params)
{
         var form = document.createElement("form");
         form.setAttribute("method", "post");
         form.setAttribute("action", url);
         form.setAttribute("target", name);
         var input = document.createElement('input');
         input.type = 'hidden';
         input.name = "PARAM";
         input.value = params;
         form.appendChild(input);
         document.body.appendChild(form);
         window.open(url, name, windowoption);
         form.submit();
         document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

Comment: when you say 'disable' the parent window.. do you mean that the user cannot click on anything on it? ie if they click on a button in the parent window while the child window is open.. the button won't respond?

Comment: yes... there shouldn't be no action in parent window when child is opened...

Comment: Rachel please let us know if any of our answers fit your needs, or why not if it didn't so that we can help you

Comment: yeah its necessary to open the child window as popup. what is the use of modal dialog and any example for that?

Comment: chris's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14888594/766570) below [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) has many examples.. just try on clicking on any of the images and you'll see what we're talking about.. but if a pop-up window is necessary.. then my answer still addresses that case

Comment: Rachel.. for people to pay attention to your questions you must in return pay attention to their answers.. please either accept one of the answers below or explain why none of them solves your problem

Comment: abbood am sorry. i was busy. i referred this link. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Modal-PopUp-using-JavaScript.aspx   and its almost same as that of your answer. its working. i got it. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

one easy way to disable a window (assuming your definition of disable matches my comment above) is to simply overlay the window with an invisible div and give it an incredibly large z-index so that if you have any other dom elements with a z-index > 1 it will still be covered by that invisible div..

try avoiding stuff like window.showModalDialog() they're [bad news](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/).. if i were you.. i wouldn't even create a new window unless it's absolutely necessary (i can't think of a single scenario to be honest).. i would just create a modal dialog within the same window using a div and css.. there are tonnes of tutorials and libraries (ie twitter bootstrap) for that online.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to open modal dialog. Check out `window.showModalDialog()` instead of `window.open()`. Note, it also has a little bit different parameters...

And also, if you want to place it before `form.submit();`, then it won't be executed until modal window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) library for creating a modal iframe.  I've used this in a few projects and it does what you ask; albeit in an overlay and not in a separate window.